# Is it possible to merge camera rolls of two different iPhones?

Tags: iphone, photos, camera-roll

I have iPhone 7 and iPhone XS Max and both of these iPhones are on the same iCloud account, but have different camera rolls.

Is there a way to copy all the photos from the iPhone 7 in to my XS Max camera? It would be great if I can keep all the existing information and store them in chronological order.

Please note: I don't use iCloud photos and have no intention of paying for it.

Comment: I’m not very sure about this approach but how about you try AirDropping photo(s) from one device to the other? You can check by sharing one photo and see it goes in the correct place with the correct metadata. It it works, you can send across all the photos and videos.